# how do you use awk to count lines that are not starting with # in multiple files and list them out with filenames?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have been using `grep "^[^#]" file.txt | wc -l` to count the number of lines in a single file.

How do I use `awk` to count the number of lines not starting with `#` and print out with file names like below?

```
file1.txt 30 
file2.txt 33
....
```

Comment: If a file is empty, should the output be `file.txt 0` or is it OK to not output the name+count for empty files? Should an empty line be counted as one that doesn't start with `#` or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can do with `awk` (same `^[^#]` in `grep` applies in the awk too but in `awk` regex match written inside pair of the slashes `/.../` (there are other ways too)):

```
find . -type f -exec \
    awk '/^[^#]/ {count++}; END{ print FILENAME, count+0 }' {} \;
```

or alternatively if you have a GNU awk for the *`ENDFILE{}`* block:

```
gawk '/^[^#]/{ count++ }; ENDFILE{ print FILENAME, count+0; count=0 }' ./multiple.files*
```

Or recursively:

```
find . -type f -exec \
    gawk '/^[^#]/{ count++ }; ENDFILE{ print FILENAME, count+0; count=0 }' {} +
```

###### Notes:

- Using `/^[^#]/` will skip counting empty lines._
- Using `!/^#/` would be the equivalent of the `/^[^#]/` conditionally only if there is no empty lines in your input otherwise `!/^#/` would count empty lines too which is what it really does and more correct when asking *"counting the lines not starting with #"*
- The exact equivalent of the `!/^#/` would be `/^([^#]|$)/` (so both would count the empty lines too)

Considering the above points, if you would like to count empty lines too as said "count the lines not starting with #", do:

```
awk '!/^#/{count++} END{ print FILENAME, count+0 }'
```

or its equally:

```
awk '/^([^#]|$)/{count++} END{ print FILENAME, count+0 }'
```

or alternatively (which is suggested by [@EdMorton](/users/133219)):

```
awk '/^#/{ count++ } END{ print FILENAME, FNR-count }'
```

and applying the same for the GNU awk form:

```
awk '/^#/{ count++ } ENDFILE{ print FILENAME, FNR-count; count=0 }'
```

if you wanted to skip printing the output when a file was full of commented lines:

```
awk '/^#/{ count++ } END{ if(count) print FILENAME, FNR-count }'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this with `grep`:

```
grep -c "^[^#]" *
```

or

```
grep -cv "^#" *
```

The former also excludes empty lines; the latter doesn’t.

Note that this won’t show the file name if there’s a single file in the current directory; you can avoid that with some versions of `grep` (including GNU `grep`) by adding the `-H` option:

```
grep -cvH "^#" *
```

GNU `grep` also supports recursive searches to descend a directory tree:

```
grep -rcvH "^#" .
```

The output doesn’t quite match what you’re asking for, it will end up like

```
file1.txt:30
file2.txt:33
```

but that can be fixed by piping the output through `sed 's/:\([^:]*\)$/ \1/'`.

Comment: You can add the `/dev/null` file to grep so that single file searches too display file names. And then take away the dummy name at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in  *
do
if [[ -f "$i" ]]
then
co=$(grep -vc "^#"  "$i" )
echo "$i $co"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```bsh
find . -type f -exec perl -lnse '
  /^#/ || $c++;
  eof  && (print($ARGV,$c),$c=0);
' -- -,=: {} +
```

---

Using POSIXly `awk`:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec awk -v OFS=: '
FNR==1 && NR>1 {
  print prev, knt+0
  knt=0
}
substr($0,1,1) != "#"{knt++}
FILENAME != prev {prev=FILENAME}
END { print prev, knt+0 }
' {} +
```